# Stereoscopic camera for depth measurement

Tags: image, image-processing, camera, stereoscopy

Been reading this paper:

http://photon07.pd.infn.it:5210/users/dazzi/Thesis_doctorate/Info/Chapter_6/Stereoscopy_(Mrovlje).pdf

to figure out how to use 2 parallel camera to find the depth of an object. Seems like some how we need the field of view of the camera at exact plane (which is the depth which the cameras try to measure anyway) to get the depth.

Am I interpreting this wrong? Or anyone else knows how does one use a pair of camera to measure distance of an object from the camera pair?

Kelvin

Comment: Do you have to use two cameras for some reason? As Vlad mentions below, the Kinect camera and other relatively inexpensive off-the-shelf sensors provide depth data. Other than that, a textbook such as An Introduction to 3D Computer Vision Techniques and Algorithms by Cyganek and Siebert would be a good start.

Comment: Hey Rethunk thanks alot. Will take a look at the textbook. I am kinda restricted by the current hardware setup( two camera) so additional light pattern generator like the one in Kinect is not possible. But anyway what I get from you guys are good enough to make progress in my development work.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad you're making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera sensors either have to lie on the same plane or their images has to be rectified so that 'virtually' they lie in the same plane. This is the only requirement and it simplifies the search for matches between the left and right image: whatever you have in the left image will be located in the right at the same row so you don't need to check other rows. You can skip this requirement but then your search will be more extensive. When you done with finding correspondences you can figure out the depth from them.

In rectified camera, the depth is determined from the shift: for example if the left image has a feature in row 4, column 11 and the left image has this feature in row 4 (same row since camera was rectified) column 1 then we say that disparity is 11-1=10. The disparity D is inversely proportional to dept Z:

Z=fB/D , where B is distance between cameras.
At the end you will have depth estimates everywhere where you found correspondences. So called dense stereo aims to get more than 90% of image area covered where sparse stereo recovers only a few depth measurements.

Note that it is hard to find correspondences if there is a little texture on the surface of the object or in other words it is uniformly colored. Some cameras such as Kinect project their own pattern on the objects to solve the problem of feature absence.

Comment: Hi Vlad thanks for replying. In my use case the the camera sensors lie on the same plan so not rectification is necessary. Thanks for clarifying things. Basically a stereo camera system uses the pixel displacement of two images taken from two sensors lying on the same plane simultaneously. The pixel displacement together with the distance between the camera and the angle of view of the lens give you the depth. Thanks!

Comment: that’s a good summary. The trick of course is to find matches even if you have to look at the same row. Typically people don’t compare pixels but instead correlate small windows around them (hence the name correlation stereo). Very often correlation is simplified to just sum of absolute differences of gradients between windows. The larger the size of the window the more reliable is your match but this comes at the cost of smaller precision. Finally, it is better to have no match  at all than inaccurate match, hence there are typically large holes in disparity maps where matches are ambiguous.

Comment: Hi Vlad thanks once again for replying. In my use case I know exactly the shape of the object I am locating and I can use simple object localization (hough transform i.e) to find the pixel coordinates of the object in both sensors. Now my main task is to find how precise can i measure depth of this said object because precision is key in the project I am currently working on. Once again thanks for being extremely helpful Vlad.

Comment: Ok, remember that disparity is related to z so a part of the object with constant disparity should have constant z that is to be a fronto-parallel patch. Only for these parts you can average disparities. Otherwise, you should assume that disparity is different at each point of your object and calculate it point-wise by matching object features in two frames. You can do this only for certain points that can be well matched, of course. Then use the formula Z=fB/D to get distance; you cal also reconstruct X = uZ/f and Y= vZ/f where u and v where u=col-w/2, v=h/2-row). What’s your object, anyway?

Comment: My object is a sphere. I am using hough transform to find the center of the sphere (a circle on 2D plane). And based on the x y pixel coordinate on both cameras I will measure the z.

Comment: By 2D plane you meant a projection of sphere on your sensor/image? Is your sphere large and has texture or it is just a small one?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, a projection of sphere on sensor. Sphere is large enough. WHy does the size/texture matters?

Comment: Well, if you match spheres and there is no other objects to match the task is really simple. The texture matters only when you cannot decide  on exact match. So you have to have pretty accurate z distance from the formulas I mentioned above given that your cameras are calibrated and images are rectified.